# UIStepper with value

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistepper

Does the UIStepper have a built in view that can show the current value? Can't find anything about this. Or do I have to create my own UILabel and increment the value in that?

Comment: You have to create your own uilabel to show the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know there is no built in label for the UIStepper's value.
But i found this on github https://github.com/shams-ahmed/SAStepperControl